# Overhead of using Panels

Tags: panels

Panels is one of the most useful modules for Drupal and many websites make use of it.
However I always have been cautious using it because of its processing overheads.
I want to know is there any benchmark or article about Panels efficiency on the net?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the only thing I recall seeing, at DrupalCon San Fran in 2010. Sam Boyer, a maintainer of Panels, discusses benchmarks a bit in this video:  http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/state-panels-3-and-more-what-you-love  at about the 29 minute mark.  It's not really a great benchmark test, but gives some idea into what page manager is running/processing.

Comment: Thank you. That was a great video. Although I didn't listen to all of it, my conclusion is I will use it!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I came to the same conclusion.  I think the answer is to use Panels where it makes sense and not to over rely on it if you can get away with simple themeing techniques...but it does come in very handy at times.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another benchmark [Performance Panels](http://www.codeenigma.com/blog/performance-panels).

> Conclusions
>
> Panels is, in general, about 20% quicker than Block. Until you add in some Views >blocks. Then big ouchy things start to happen (we haven't investigated why that >is yet). Those big ouchy things *only* affect Block and not Panels. So all of a >sudden Panels becomes about 100% quicker than Block